# Override localization via multiple domains

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, localization, dns

I have 2 domains, .eu and .de and I have one mvc3 website running on my webserver.

Now we want the following behavior:

Both domains are pointing to the same mvc3 project (this works already fine)
The .de domain should now show the project de-DE localized and the .eu domain has to show the english localized project.... But how?

Any help is welcome... thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your ConrollerBase or from global.asax you can parse the url using the [URI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) class.

Then you can simply look for the last part of the Host and based on the result (.de or .eu) load a Culture or an other.

Comment: I would recommend that a new action filter is created for this. SRP.